# 'PLS-00103' and 'ORA-06550' Errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have several blocks that I'm unable to run in Oracle SQL Developer 18.2.0.183. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in my blocks or if I need to make some change to the developer. The below block outputs, "Error starting at line : 1 in command -." (for declare).

```
declare
total_purchases number(7,2);
begin
total_purchases :=20;
case
when (total_purchases>200) then dbms_output.put_line(‘high’);
when (total_purchases>100) and total_purchases<200) then dbms_output.put_line(‘mid);
when (total_purchases<100) then dbms_output.put_line(‘low’);
end case;
end
```

It also outputs the following:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you writing your sql in MS Word? you're using angled quotes, except no human probably ever does that - they use straight ones and their word processor converts them. recommend using a basic text editor or query tool to write sql...

Answer (score 1):

I mark with "^"

```
declare
  total_purchases number(7,2);
begin
  total_purchases :=20;
  case 
       when (total_purchases>200) then dbms_output.put_line('high');
       when ((total_purchases>100) and total_purchases<200) then dbms_output.put_line('mid');
            ^                                                                             ^
       when (total_purchases<100) then dbms_output.put_line('low');
  end case;
end;
   ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a two typo in

```
when (total_purchases>100) and total_purchases<200) then dbms_output.put_line(‘mid);
```

Replace with

```
when (total_purchases>100 and total_purchases<200) then dbms_output.put_line(‘mid‘);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quote ('') not and also case was not defined properly

```
declare
total_purchases number(7,2);
begin
   total_purchases :=20;
   case
      when (total_purchases>200) then dbms_output.put_line('high');
      when (total_purchases>100) and total_purchases<200) then 
      dbms_output.put_line('mid');
      when (total_purchases<100) then dbms_output.put_line('low');
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that - put `CASE` into `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` call:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2     total_purchases   NUMBER (7, 2);
  3  BEGIN
  4     total_purchases := 20;
  5     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (CASE
  6                              WHEN total_purchases > 200
  7                              THEN
  8                                 'high'
  9                              WHEN     total_purchases > 100
 10                                   AND total_purchases < 200
 11                              THEN
 12                                 'mid'
 13                              WHEN total_purchases < 100
 14                              THEN
 15                                 'low'
 16                           END);
 17  END;
 18  /
low

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Or, if you use your syntax, fix errors first (superfluous parenthesis, missing semi-colon):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     total_purchases   NUMBER (7, 2);
  3  BEGIN
  4     total_purchases := 20;
  5
  6     CASE
  7        WHEN (total_purchases > 200)
  8        THEN
  9           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('high');
 10        WHEN     (total_purchases > 100)
 11             AND total_purchases < 200
 12        THEN
 13           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('mid');
 14        WHEN (total_purchases < 100)
 15        THEN
 16           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('low');
 17     END CASE;
 18  END;
 19  /
low

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```